# Parsing an object inside an object with serde_json

Tags: json, rust, serde, hyper, serde-json

I am stuck, below is the JSON which I am receiving:

```
{
   "BCH": {
      "aclass": "currency",
      "altname": "BCH",
      "decimals": 10,
      "display_decimals": 5
   }
}
```

I am bit confused on how my struct should look like to parse the attributes using the`serde_json` crate. Below is what I currently have:

```
#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
struct Assets  {  
    aclass: String,
    altname: String,
    decimals: u8,
    display_decimals: u8,
}

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
struct Currency {
    assest: Assets,
}


fn to_assets_type(value: serde_json::Value) -> Currency {
 serde_json::from_value(value).unwrap()
}
```

I am getting an error message:

> thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err`
>   value: ErrorImpl { code: Message("missing field `assest`"), line: 0,
>   column: 0 }', src/libcore/result.rs:860:4

Comment: Looks like your `json` is an object inside an object ....

Comment: I cannot test my intuition now, but I think you should try to rename your `Currency` asset field to `BCH`.

Comment: BCH is not static

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you want a HashMap.

```
#[macro_use] extern crate serde;
extern crate serde_json;

use std::collections::HashMap;

static VALUE: &str = r#"{
   "BCH": {
      "aclass": "currency",
      "altname": "BCH",
      "decimals": 10,
      "display_decimals": 5
   }
}"#;

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
struct Assets {  
    aclass: String,
    altname: String,
    decimals: u8,
    display_decimals: u8,
}

fn main() {
    let serde_value: HashMap<String, Assets> = serde_json::from_str(VALUE).unwrap();

    println!("{:?}", serde_value);
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=214cd875a36ae21d623812f36817b0ce&version=stable)